# Given n, find the maximum numbers added to get n

Tags: c, algorithm

Question asked in oracle interview.For example,if my input is 6, then

- 5+1=6   Ans:2
- 4+2=6   Ans:2
- 3+2+1=6 Ans:3

So, the final answer should be 3.(i.e 3,2,1 are needed to get sum 6)

**Note**:Repetition of number isn't allowed (i.e 1+1+1+1+1+1=6)

I solved it using recursion but interviewer wasn't satisfied. Is Dynamic Programming possible?

Comment: this question seems familiar, is it from school or from Project Euler?

Comment: The question has a constant solution with no need of recursion that is why the interviewer is was not satisfied.

Comment: Recursion cause lot of stack usage. Try using loop and conditions.

Comment: do you need no two numbers on the lhs be equal?

Comment: What if you must repeat? Think of the case of n = 9. It is impossible to have not a repeated number.

Comment: @Desolator why it is impossible?

Comment: @Desolator there is at least one sequence of non-repeating positive integers that sum up to 9 (namely, the one-element sequence {9}). There is a finite number of such sequences. Therefore there's one with maximum length among them (for instance {2,3,4} is one such, there are others with the same length).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was about to post the answer but @Cruise Liu beat me to it. Ill try explaining it a bit .
Its a type of integer partitioning but you dont need to generate the elements since you're only interested in the 'number of elements'. i.e. the final answer 3 and not {1, 2, 3}

Given a number N, you have another restriction that numbers cannot repeat.
Hence the best case would be if N is actually a number say 1, 3, 6, 10, 15

```
i.e. f(x) = x * (x + 1) / 2.
```

For example, take 6. f(x) = 6 exists. specifically f(3) = 6 . Thus you get the answer 3.

What this means is that if there is an integer X that exists for f(x) = N, then there is a set of numbers 1, 2, 3 ... x that when added up give N. And this is the maximum number possible (without repitition).

However, there are cases in f(x) = N where x is not an integer.

```
f(x) = x * (x + 1 ) / 2 = N
i.e. x**2 + x = 2*N
x**2 + x - 2*N = 0
```

Solving this quadratic we get

[image: quadratic solved]

Since the number x is not negative we can't have

[image: not possible]

So we're left with

[image: left with]

For N = 6

[image: n equals 6]

A perfect Integer. But for N = 12

[image: n equals 12]

which is 8.845 / 2 which is a fraction. The floor value is 4, which is the answer.

In short: Implement a function 
f(N) = (int) ((-1.0 + sqrt(1 + 8*N))/2.0 )

i.e.

```
int max_partition_length(int n){
    return (int)((-1.0 + sqrt(1 + n*8))/2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot @JDS . After reading ur review, i checked online. The easiest way is to generate the formulae with laTeX and add it as an image here ? (thats all i got from all the questions on laTeX here.. the rest say its possible only on math and physics forums).

Comment: Yes, basically it's that. I used [LaTeXiT](http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/latexit/index.php?lang=en) (I don't know if there is something similar for Windows/Linux) for automatically cropping the resulting image.

Answer (score 10):

The minimum sum of x numbers is

[image: minimum sum]

So just find x that satisfies the inequality:

[image: inequality formula]

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int x = 1;
    while ((x+1)*x/2 <= n) x++;
    x--; // now (x+1)*x/2 > n , so x is too large
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

You can use binary search if n is very large.

Comment: Where did you get this formula?

Comment: (x+1)*x/2<=n means it's possible to find x numbers which add up to n; n<(x+2)*(x+1)/2 means it's impossible to find x+1 numbers add up to n, because the sum of x+1 numbers is always greater than or equal to (x+2)*(x+1)/2

Comment: You can also use functions like `sqrt` and avoid (or rather hide in the standard library) any loops.

Comment: @n.m. yes, x = floor((sqrt(8*n+1)-1)/2). But I think it's pure math and hard to understand...

Comment: @cruiseLiu thanks for your reply.But it is not that the sum always from 1 to x.Example for 9 1+2+6=9 .

Comment: That's a quadratic equation. Should a programmer be expected to solve quadratic equations?

Comment: @abi let me try to explain it by example. 1+2+3=6. 1+2+3+4=10. 9 is less than 10 so you cannot represent it as a sum of 4 numbers. But you can remove exactly one number from that set of 4 (which one? 1+2+3+4-9=1) and get 9. Indeed, 2+3+4=9.

Comment: @abi first, for N = 1 + 2 + .. + x form, there could be at most x number partition (obvious). same for M = 1 + 2 .. + (x-1), the maximum number of partition is x-1.

Comment: @abi (cont.)
For all number in [M+1, N-1], the maximum number of partition is at least **x-1**, since we could construct a partition by  1+..+(x-2)+remaining.

Assume it's possible to partition in to x number, then consider first (x-1) number in partition by order. the sum of them is larger than M, and the (x-1)th number is larger equal than x-1. but the remaining part is less equal than x-1. Hence, it's not possible partition it into x number.